# Applications that can be run in hadoop YARN

Tags: hadoop, distributed-computing, hadoop2

It is known that YARN can execute/run a variety of applications such as MapReduce, hive, pig, hbase, impala, spark, etc. I would like to know of a comprehensive list of the various kinds or types of applications that can be run on Hadoop YARN data processing environment other than the above mentioned. Thanks!

Note: The question is more about non-hadoop-stack distributed applications that can be executed in YARN.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From http://hortonworks.com/hadoop/yarn/ may give you some insight.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm quite familiar with hadoop stack landscape. The question is more about non-hadoop stack distributed applications that can be executed in YARN.